# Why I'm getting duplicated data from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
public class Post {

    private String title;
    private String massage;

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getMassage() {
        return massage;
    }

    public void setMassage(String massage) {
        this.massage = massage;
    }
}

public class Posts extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference, barRoomsCoordinates;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private List<Post> postList;
    private List<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

        postList = new ArrayList<>();
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        showAllMyPosts();


    }

    private void getPosts(List<String> posts) {

        for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
            databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Posts").child(posts.get(i));
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Post posts = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    Post post = new Post();

                    post.setTitle(posts.getTitle());
                    post.setMassage(posts.getMassage());
                    postList.add(post);



                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void showAllMyPosts() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Posts.this);

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                barRoomsCoordinates = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Posts");
                barRoomsCoordinates.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
                        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                            list.add(((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getKey());
                        }
                        getPosts(list);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

This is my database structure

```
Posts
 Post1
 message1: 
"abc + something"
 title1: 
"abc"
 Post2
 message2: 
"def + something"
 title2: 
"def"
 Post3
 message3: 
"ghi + something"
 title3: 
"ghi"
```

I'm getting duplicated array and can't understand why
please help me.
I also tried delete one reference and make a call but in this way I can't access the children of the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of your `for loop`. You are creating a new `databaseReference` every time you loop. Take the `databaseReference` out of your loop and it will solve your problem or try to change the logic of getting the data from your Firebase database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: in first reference i'm fetching the Post1,Post2,Post3 list and then i'm trying get the children title and message of each post.                                                 {
  "Post1" : {
    "message1" : "abc + something",
    "title1" : "abc"
  },
  "Post2" : {
    "message2" : "def + something",
    "title2" : "def"
  },
  "Post3" : {
    "message3" : "ghi + something",
    "title3" : "ghi"
  }
}

Comment: Please add your database structure to the post and what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Posts:
Post1
message1 : "abc + something"
title1 : "abc"
Post2
message2 : "def + something"
title2 : "def"
Post3
message3 : "ghi + something"
title3 : "ghi"

Comment: postsRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Posts"); databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Posts").child(posts.get(i));

Comment: i created two references from the first i'm getting the array with post1 post2 etc. after i'm makiing the second reference for achieving the children as i explaned above. databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Posts").child(posts.g‌​et(i) = post1);

Comment: Please update your original post to include the database structure.

Comment: Hi Drew my database structure you can find in my comments above and also i updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

public class Posts extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference, barRoomsCoordinates;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private List<Post> postList;
private List<String> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

    postList = new ArrayList<>();
    list = new ArrayList<>();

    getPosts();


}

private void getPosts() {

    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Posts");
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Iterator iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Post post = new Post();
                post.setTitle((String) ((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue());
                post.setMassage((String) ((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue());

                postList.add(post);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Hello all,

I solved my problem with one reference to the database instead of two calls as i did before and with addChildEventListener.

Thanks